# VS 2010: Solution Explorer->Add New Item->"Application Manifest File" Is Missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-power-tools

I'm using VS2010 Ultimate

Recently:
In the "Add New Item" dialog box the Item "Application Manifest File"  not exist,
Why it's missing?
Does anyone know how to redisplay that item?
Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try running `devenv /setup` from the Visual Studio command prompt so that Visual Studio will rebuild the list of templates.

Comment: @jessehouwing still the same

Comment: i found the solution, thanks anyway

Comment: Can you share the solution as an answer, so others won't have to keep looking?